# React & Redux tslint Warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, tslint

When I use react and redux. The `connect` method causes below tslint warning/error (I am not 100% sure about this statement too). Component works but looking at the tslint error is killing me.

type definition is this `interface IPrivateMenuItem extends StateProps, IMenuItem, IOwnProps {}`

> Type '{ children: string; icon: "user"; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<IPrivateMenuItem, "hasAnyAuthorities" | "id" | "to" | "icon"> & IOwnProps'.
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<IPrivateMenuItem, "hasAnyAuthorities" | "id" | "to" | "icon"> & IOwnProps'.ts(2322)

I tried component definition like `const PrivateMenuItem: React.FC<IPrivateMenuItem>`. But no chance the warning gone. Unless I remove the connect statement. Which is not possible due to redux requirement.

Then, I switch the functional component's prop type to **IPrivateMenuItem** as defined below. Then the issue is gone. My question is if this is the best practice or is there an easier one ?

`interface IPrivateMenuItem extends StateProps, IMenuItem, React.PropsWithChildren<IOwnProps> {}`

The full functional component code without imports is

```
interface IOwnProps {
  hasAnyAuthorities?: string[];
}

interface IPrivateMenuItem extends StateProps, IMenuItem, React.PropsWithChildren<IOwnProps> {}

const PrivateMenuItem = ({ isAuthorized, id, to, icon, children }: IPrivateMenuItem) => {
  return isAuthorized ? (
    <MenuItem id={id} to={to} icon={icon}>
      {children}
    </MenuItem>
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ authentication: { account } }: IRootState, { hasAnyAuthorities = [] }: IOwnProps) => ({
  isAuthorized: hasAnyAuthority(account.authorities, hasAnyAuthorities),
});

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard without seeing the whole component but if it helps

The full typing for a connect is the following

`connect<TheMapStateToPropsType, TheDispatchToPropsType, TheComponentPropsType, TheStorePropsType>`

You can type you component like this : (I am doing it with a class but you get the spirit for a functional component )

```
interface OwnProps { }
interface StateProps { }
interface DispatchProps { }

type Props = OwnProps & StateProps & DispatchProps; 

export class MyComponent extends Component<Props> { } 

const mapStateToProps = (state): StateProps => ({ 
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch): DispatchProps => {
    return {
    }
}


export default connect<StateProps,DispatchProps,OwnProps,StorePropsIfYouWant>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks, I added my way of fixing it. Plus it's a bit different compared to Class based component definition. Cuz the problem is with ReactComponent's default props types to be included.